# how to find the status of executed MSI from the command prompt

Tags: wix, wix3.6, windows-installer

I have created an installer using WiX and it will be executed using the command prompt. What I'm looking for is a way to check the status of the same when it is executed using the command prompt without checking the event log or installer log.

Find the code snippet below.

```
<Property Id="ISSQLSERVERINSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="IsSqlExpressServiceInstalled" Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ClientSetup\CurrentVersion"
                  Name="CurrentVersion" Type="raw"/>
</Property>
<Condition Message="Microsoft SQL Server 2005 must be installed">
  <![CDATA[ Installed OR ISSQLSERVERINSTALLED ]]>
</Condition>
```

I'm using the msiexec /i command to install the package and after installation I have checked the %errorlevel% variable but it returns 0 even the installation fails. Is there any way to set an error code in a condition or is there any other way to check the status of the installation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As Ciprian said, you can enable logging using `msiexec /i "C:\...\setup.msi" /l*xv log.txt`. Then use `net helpmsg 0000` to know what each error message means. For example 1603 is fatal error during installation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't want to use the log. What I want is, check errorlevel after run msiexec /i msiname.msi

Answer (score 1):

In case of a failed launch condition the %errorlevel% is set to 1603. Create an install log for details on what really goes wrong.

Comment: when I run the msi through command line, msiexec /i msiname.msi It gives the message "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 must be installed" which is specified in above code. But then I run the echo %errorlevel% in same command line window, it gives '0', which I expect some error code like 1603